Implementation of FTBS scheme for LWR model in Python
I'm implementing the FTBS (Forward-Time Backward-Space) scheme for the LWR (Lighthill-Whitham-Richards) traffic flow model.
However, I encountered a runtime error:
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in scalar:

subtract rho[i] = rho_n[i] - dt / dx * (flux(rho_n[i]) - flux(max(rho_n[i - 1], 0)))

.
This warning suggests that there might be an issue with the calculation involving density differences. I'll need to investigate further to ensure that the density remains within valid bounds throughout the simulation.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Constants
vf = 30  # Free-flow speed (m/s)
K = 0.1  # Maximum density (veh/m)
dx = 0.001  # Spatial grid size (km)
dt = 0.001  # Time step size (hours)
L = 1.0  # Length of the road (km)
nt = 1000  # Number of time steps

# Initial condition
rho0 = np.zeros(int(L / dx))
rho0[:int(0.5 * len(rho0))] = 0.05  # Initial density (veh/m)

# Function to calculate flux
def flux(rho):
    return vf * rho * (1 - rho / K)

# FTBS scheme with density bounds check
def ftbs_scheme(rho, nt, dt, dx):
    rho_hist = [rho.copy()]
    for n in range(nt):
        rho_n = rho.copy()
        for i in range(1, len(rho) - 1):
            rho[i] = rho_n[i] - dt / dx * (flux(rho_n[i]) - flux(max(rho_n[i - 1], 0)))
        rho_hist.append(rho.copy())
    return rho_hist

# Perform simulation
rho_hist = ftbs_scheme(rho0, nt, dt, dx)

# Plot results
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
plt.plot(np.linspace(0, L, len(rho0)), rho0, label='Initial')
plt.plot(np.linspace(0, L, len(rho0)), rho_hist[-1], label='Final')
plt.xlabel('Distance (km)')
plt.ylabel('Density (veh/m)')
plt.title('FTBS Scheme for LWR Traffic Flow Model')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()

